# Android Studio FragmentManger POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, fragmentmanager

I'm imitating a project to study, and the original study,

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.popBackStack(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.getBackStackEntryAt(0).id, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

it worked.

and now on my project I copied and pasted, and it's automatically changed like below

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.popBackStack(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.getBackStackEntryAt(0).id,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

the end of the code is different.
and I must write FragmentManger.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE, not just POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSE. If I write only POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE, then it makes error.

I don't know why it's happened like this. WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original project, the `FragmentManager` has been imported in the file, so you don't need to specify it again.

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
```

Try to add it into the top of your file and see if it works. If not, you may find a similar line in your original project, copy that into your file and it should work